# Custom syntax highlighting for light and dark mode Quarto

Tags: r, yaml, pandoc, quarto

I am trying to use different syntax highlighting for light and dark mode in Quarto, per the documentation [here](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-code.html#highlighting). However, I cannot get this documented method to work.

Here's an example. My regular file looks like this, with one highlight style for light and dark.

````
---
title: "Example"
format:
    html:
        theme:
            light: flatly
            dark: darkly
highlight-style: github
eval: false
---

```{r}
# Trivial code
library(tidyverse)

mtcars <- mtcars |>
    group_by(mpg) |>
    distinct() |>
    ungroup() |>
    mutate(id = row_number())
```
````

Per the documentation, I should be able to add different highlight styles for light and dark. I tried two options, both of which just removed all syntax highlighting from both light and dark modes.

First, I tried:

````
---
title: "Example"
format:
    html:
        theme:
            light: flatly
            dark: darkly
highlight-style: 
    light: github
    dark: atom-one
eval: false
---

```{r}
# Trivial code
library(tidyverse)

mtcars <- mtcars |>
    group_by(mpg) |>
    distinct() |>
    ungroup() |>
    mutate(id = row_number())
```
````

Next, I tried:

````
---
title: "Example"
format:
    html:
        theme:
            light: flatly
            dark: darkly
        highlight-style:
            light: github
            dark: atom-one
eval: false
---

```{r}
# Trivial code
library(tidyverse)

mtcars <- mtcars |>
    group_by(mpg) |>
    distinct() |>
    ungroup() |>
    mutate(id = row_number())
```
````

Both of these options, attempting to follow the documentation, just remove all code highlighting. Does anyone know how to properly use two different code highlighting themes for light and dark mode in Quarto? I am using the newest version of Quarto, `v1.4.549`, on Mac OS Sonoma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't mix-and-match the `highlight-style` for light and dark unless you import `.theme` files (which is the example in the documentation).

One option is to use a single highlighting theme which has both light and dark variants, e.g. `highlight-style: atom-one` will automatically switch between `atom-one-light` and `atom-one-dark`.

Otherwise you can download different light and dark theme files from [the quarto cli Github page](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/tree/main/src/resources/pandoc/highlight-styles), save them locally to `.theme` files in the same directory and then use:

```
highlight-style: 
  light: testlight.theme
  dark: testdark.theme
```

Example output with oblivion for the light theme and espresso for the dark theme (Windows OS):
[image: Light output]
[image: Dark output]

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work? Even when using custom `.theme` files, I have found that Quarto just uses the first `.theme` file it sees for both light and dark themes

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the code highlighting being applied separately to both light and dark output (on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use different highlight styles for light and dark this, I need to use custom `.theme` files. With a `.theme` file, any of my attempted YAML options will work.

However, I couldn't tell that the custom themes were working because I really wanted to change the base text color in code chunks, and none of the fields in the `.theme` files seemed to change this. In addition to the syntax highlighting options, the `.theme` file needs to include the "Normal" field, which can change the base code font color in the custom syntax highlighting theme.

For example, the `.theme` files needs to include:

```
{
    "text-styles": {
        "Normal" : {
            "text-color" : "#f9f9f9"
        },
    # More syntax highlighting options
}
```

Then, with a Quarto file that looks like:

````
---
title: "Example"
format:
    html:
        theme:
            light: flatly
            dark: darkly
        highlight-style:
            light: custom-light.theme
            dark: custom-dark.theme
eval: false
---

```{r}
# Trivial code
library(tidyverse)

mtcars <- mtcars |>
    group_by(mpg) |>
    distinct() |>
    ungroup() |>
    mutate(id = row_number())
```
````

we can get to distinct light and dark syntax highlighting themes with different base font colors:

[image]
[image]

Now, we have two different syntax highlighting styles, including two distinct code base font colors. For help developing your own custom syntax highlighting theme, try forking [this repo](https://github.com/EmilHvitfeldt/quarto-syntax-theme-editor/tree/main) to test your colors.